# Erro ao adicionar criar um componente utilizando PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

Fala galera blz? Tô aprendendo primeng mas não to conseguindo rodar meu projeto. Fiz os passos certinho da documentação e vejo que estou com error aqui mas não consegui solucionar.

Passos que eu fiz foi: instalei o primeNg e primeicons.

```
Adicionei no package.json:

"styles": [
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css", 
Adicionei um componente no html
```

meu HTML

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Click" ></button>
```

**module.app**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, ButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Ao rodar o projeto, recebo esse error:

```
Error: node_modules/primeng/ripple/ripple.d.ts:26:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/daysonrodrigues/Documents/algamoney/algamoney-api/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

26     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<RippleModule>;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: ./node_modules/primeng/fesm2015/primeng-button.js 218:10-28
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Comment: Provavelmente a versão q está utilizando não é compatível. Qual é a sua versão do angular e a versão do primeng?

Answer (score 0):

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
]
```

você precisa adicionar isso no angular.json e não no package.json.

Já existe, por definição, um array chamado `styles` no angular.json, dentro do objeto `build`.